# How to pass div id value to PHP variable?

Tags: php

I am using an auto complete form to find "lat" and "lng" for a city name and it works fine. I get the correct values in div id="lat" and div id="lng" but I want to use these values in php variables as $latitude="lat" and $longitude="lng" to use them in a php script that needs $latitude and $longitude?
I have been trying many of the solutions presented here, but my knowledge is too short to make it work. 
The script is:

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=MY_KEY&libraries=places">
 </script>

 <script>
 function initialize() {
    var address = (document.getElementById('city-input'));
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(address);
    autocomplete.setTypes(['geocode']);
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() 
 {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (!place.geometry) {
            return;
        }

    var address = '';
    if (place.address_components) {
        address = [
            (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
            (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
            ].join(' ');
    }
    document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML = place.geometry.location.lat();
    document.getElementById('lng').innerHTML = place.geometry.location.lng();
    });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

   </script>

   <input id="city-input" class="controls" type="text"
    placeholder="Enter a location">
   <div id="lat"></div>
   <div id="lng"></div>
```

---

And for the php part I am trying this with no result at all

```
   <?php 
    $latitude = (isset($_GET['lat']))?$_GET['lat']:'';
    $longitude = (isset($_GET['lng']))?$_GET['lng']:'';   
    echo $latitude;
    echo $longitude;
    ?>
```

Is there any way to do what I intend to do? (get $latitude and $longitude with the values that were correctly obtained from googleapis?)
Thank you so much for any precious help :-)

Comment: Do you mean, you don't get value of lat and long when post back to server? look like city-input? if it is so, you could use input with type hidden to save value of lat and long and set value for it below: document.getElementById('long').innerHTML = place.geometry.location.lng();

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for confusing vanialla JS with jquery. But I'm trying my best to help.

You can do it using ajax
get the lat value and long value and pass it to ajax data. lets call it 
latjs and lonjs

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "lat_lon.php",
            data: "lat="+latjs+"&lon="+lonjs,
            success: function (html) {

                if (html === 'true') {
```

at the php side, capture it this way:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

if($data != null) {
    parse_str($data, $output);

$output_lan = $output['lat'];

$output_lon = $output['lon'];

blah blah process
}

Comment: Thank you so much for your precious help. I think this can be a solution and I am going to work around it and will let you know the results. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The last 2 assignment code is wrong:

```
document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML = place.geometry.location.lat();
document.getElementById('long').innerHTML = place.geometry.location.lng();
```

The above should be

```
$("#lat").html(place.geometry.location.lat());
$("#long").html(place.geometry.location.lng());
```

the code is not 100% working, but should be in the above lines. no need to use get elementbyID and all.

Hope this helps
VInay KR

Comment: I am not sure this was given negative. as itworked in comp

Comment: I asume because you're using jQuery instead of vanilla JS to select the IDs lat and long. It isn't used anywhere else in the code, so will just confuse the author.

Comment: @vinay K R 2 thank you so much for you reply. I edited the original code to make it more understanble (I hope).The original code is working perfectly as I get correct numeric values for lat and lng. Replacing those 2 lines as you sugested, also gives me  correct values. The problem remais the same: how can I pass those values to variables like $latitude and $longitde to use them on a php script? Thanks.